# HTML <script> src url no longer works after rearranging files

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a personal project in order to learn web dev, and I've run into a strange (and hopefully easily solved) problem. In my index.html file I've included a reference to a main.js file, and that's been working just fine for a while now. However, I've recently rewritten the project in Typescript and I've decided to rearrange the folder structure. The problem is that when I move my index.html file (and some other files) down one directory and append a '../' to the script's 'src' tag, I get a 404 error when the html attempts to load the script.

```
This works just fine:  
.  
|-scripts  
     |-Main.ts  
     |-Main.js  
     |-SlideShowView.ts  
     |-SlideShowView.js  
|-Server.ts  
|-Server.js  
|-index.html -> <script src="scripts/Main.js" type="module"></script> 



This does not:
.  
|-scripts  
     |-Main.ts  
     |-Main.js  
     |-SlideShowView.ts  
     |-SlideShowView.js  
|-services
     |-Server.ts  
     |-Server.js  
     |-index.html -> <script src="../scripts/Main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Connecting to the site when using the second scheme gives this error:
`GET http://localhost:8000/scripts/Main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
Is index.html not allowed to look above it's own directory? Is there a permissions issue or something? It's such a simple thing that's failing to work I figure there must be something small I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to understand the difference between URL and directory path.
first is accessible via net resource, and it's WebServer decide what to show and from which folder. In your case it's probably some node-js server ruled by some bundler, probably webpack; please share your configurations (webpack.config, package.json), so we don't need to guess

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

After I moved index.html back to root, the problem wasn't in my html or main.js, but in the express server I was using:

```
import path from "path";  
import express from "express";  

const serverPortNum = 8000;  
const htmlFile = path.join(__dirname + '/../index.html'); //Added an escape here...  

// Create html server  
var app = express();  
app.use(express.static(__dirname));// ...but not here.   
app.get('/', function(req: any, res: any)  
{  
  res.sendFile(htmlFile);  
});  

app.listen(serverPortNum, function()  
{  
  console.log("Listening! (port " + serverPortNum + ")");  
});
```

Basically, I had changed the path to the html file correctly but I forgot to make the change in app.use() as well. Changing that line to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/.."));` corrected the problem.

Answer (score -2):

This should be simple as moving the index.html file outside of both file structures

```
|-scripts  
     |-Main.ts  
     |-Main.js  
     |-SlideShowView.ts  
     |-SlideShowView.js  
|-services
     |-Server.ts  
     |-Server.js  
|-index.html -> <script src="scripts/Main.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I tried what you suggested and made the appropriate changes to paths in Server.ts and index.html, but somehow I'm still getting the same error. Does the location of Server.js determine the html's root directory somehow? I've tried both "scripts/Main.js" and "../scripts/Main.js", but neither work.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your server.js file is doing, but maybe try removing the "type="module" from the script tag as I don't think that is necessary and could be causing you issues

Comment: Just figured it out!
EDIT: okay I can't get my code to format in a comment correctly. Basically, the server is really simple and just sends the html file, and I had changed that path just fine. However, I forgot to change the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` as well, so my root directory was messed up. I changed it to  `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/.."));`  and now it works just fine. Thanks for the help!